# Uncaught Type Error: Cannont set Property 'valueAsDate' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am getting this weird error that I attempting to debug. I have an input field that has the current time pre-displayed as the value. When I run the page I get the Uncaught Type error referring to the JavaScript file line number 8 (`document.getElemntByID("theTime").valueAsDate=b;`)

Is it trying to say `ValueAsDate` is not defined? What do I put in place of it? Any help is most appreciated.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
       <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="Scripts/Global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
          
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Design.css">
   </head>
         <body>         
               <form action="" method="post">
                  <fieldset>
                     <table border="0px" >
                        <tr>
                           <td colspan = "2" id="formHeader">
                              Select Date and Time
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="date" id="theDate"></td>
                           <td  align="center" class="spaceUnder"  id="formBody">Time: &nbsp;<input type="time" id="theTime" ></td>
                        </tr>                     
                     </table>
                  </fieldset>
               </form> 
         </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myTimer();
});
function myTimer() {
    var a = new Date();
    var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours() - 8, a.getMinutes());
    //$("#theTime")[0].valueAsDate = b;
    document.getElementById("theTime").valueAsDate =b;
}
```

Comment: The error message `Cannot set Property 'valueAsDate' of null` implies that `document.getElementById("theTime")` is null.

Comment: valueAsDate is nothing.... an 'id' or something that was from the past. I tried changing to .value or .innerhtml...and even tried just document.getElemnetById("theTime)=b;  not working either

Comment: I do not see any error.

Answer (score 3):

**The question should have been how to set input type date and input type time with current values in javascript.**

And this just so that any one who searches this question in future may get help.
Because I did not find any answers on SO related to this.

Input type date expects date in this [format](http://htmlref.labs.oreilly.com/beta/element-input-date.html) yyyy-mm-dd.

Input time type expects time in this [format](http://htmlref.labs.oreilly.com/beta/element-input-time.html) hh:rr:ss format.

So the following function should do the task.

```
       function myTimer() {
         var dateObj = new Date();
         document.getElementById('theDate').value = dateObj.toISOString().slice(0,10);
         document.getElementById('theTime').value = dateObj.toTimeString().slice(0,8);
       }
```

But these features are not yet fully supported in all browsers.

I tested it in chrome and safari and it is working fine.

Comment: the date and time are not auto inserted though upon loading>>?

Answer (score 2):

Its type is time, not date

```
<input type="time" id="theTime">
```

"`document.getElemnetById("theTime)`" is **TIME**

```
var b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours() - 8, a.getMinutes());
```

b is **DATE**.

Try something like this,

```
b.setTime(document.getElementById("theTime"));
b.setHours(b.getHours() - 8);
```

Comment: When I try this,the time does not get auto inserted.. the error is gone though

Comment: the time is not auto inserting... I am not getting any errors

Comment: the date is auto inserting....... because I have this at the bottom of the script  
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = new Date();
    var b = a.getMonth() + 1;
    var c = a.getDate();
    if (b < 10) b = "0" + b;
    if (c < 10) c = "0" + c;
    var d = a.getFullYear() + "-" + b + "-" + c;
    $("#theDate").val(d);
});                                                                                                                            I tried doing the same for time, but I kept getting 'time is not defined'

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    var a = new time();
    var b = a.getTime();
    $("#theTime").val(b);
});